# Why would you use Path.Direction.CW and CCW in android?

Tags: android, path, direction

I can't find any explanation as to why a closed shape, added to a Path would want to be Clockwise or Counterclockwise and what would it mean for a closed shape, say an Oval to be added CW o CCW to a path, in the end you would still get and oval added to a path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values define the winding of your path. It becomes important depending on your fill type (see `Path.FillType`). Here is an article that provides a fairly clear explanation of how winding rules affect path rendering: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/01/30/winding-rules-in-canvas/ (Winding rules are not Android specific.)

Comment: Broken link, also not accessible via Google's cache.

Comment: This StylingAndroid article helped: https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawable-fill-windings/. It talks about these rules in the `VectorDrawable` context - the "non-zero" rule explained there == `Path.FillType.WINDING`.